# iOS How to load photo from camera to parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How can i load photo from camera or phone library to parse, like PFFile?

How to load image from assets i know, my code:

```
    func loadImage() {
       let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")

    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        let firstObject = objects?.first as PFObject?
        let objectFile = firstObject?.object(forKey: "avatar") as! PFFile
        objectFile.getDataInBackground(block: { (imageData, error) in
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            if image != nil {
                self.avatar.image = image
            }
        })
    }

}
```

This code upload image from assets. 
But i need upload from camera or library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. 
call `displayUploadImageDialog` func on button click. it will open dialog and when you select any image from photos than below `delegate` method calls.

```
func displayUploadImageDialog(btnSelected: UIButton) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Action on Upload", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel action"), style: .cancel, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            alertController.dismiss(animated: true) {() -> Void in }
        })
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        let takePhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Take Photo", comment: "Take Photo action"), style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .pad {
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({() -> Void in
                    picker.sourceType = .camera
                    self.present(picker, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
                })
            }
            else {
                if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                    let passwordAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Device has no camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let yesButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                        //Handel your yes please button action here
                        passwordAlert.dismiss(animated: true) {() -> Void in }
                    })
                    passwordAlert.addAction(yesButton)
                    self.present(passwordAlert, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
                }
                else {
                    picker.sourceType = .camera
                    self.present(picker, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
                }
            }
        })
        alertController.addAction(takePhotoAction)
        let cameraRollAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Camera Roll", comment: "Camera Roll action"), style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .pad {
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({() -> Void in
                    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                    self.present(picker, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
                })
            }
            else {
                picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                self.present(picker, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
            }
        })
        alertController.addAction(cameraRollAction)
        alertController.view.tintColor = Colors.NavTitleColor
        present(alertController, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
    }


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    var user = PFUser.current()
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.05)
    let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.jpg", data:imageData!)
    user!["profilePicture"] = imageFile;
    user?.saveInBackground(block: nil)

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: Ho i can run this func? (from button or something else?)

Comment: these are not function, these are delegate methods of `UIImagePickerController`. If you want to execute code on button click refer updated answer.

Comment: Actually this line is to check current device wether it's `iPhone` or `iPad`. It your app is develop for only `iPhone` than refer update answer or if you app is develop for `universal` than please let me know.